# To have CTRL-B to make text bold in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, edits

I would like to have similar editing possibilities with keyboard shortcuts in comments as in writing questions.

I find myself typing `Ctrl-B` at the moment too often in the comment section.

Please, **add keyboard shortcuts to comments.**

Comment: Highlighting comments was an after thought.

Comment: @Jeff: Please, explain the reason for your decision.

Comment: @Masi - Jeff and the team is under no obligation to explain their reasons. Also starting a bounty for these questions doesn't help when they are already tracking the feature-request tag. PLease refrain from these practises and sit back and watch how it is being done by others?

Comment: -1 For starting Bounties on items already flagged as Feature Requests

Comment: Maybe I simply do not know how things work exactly, but I doubt the bounty was started to attract attention (or a positive answer) from Jeff and the team. I'd expect the bounty to have been started to invite others to give their (positive or negative) opinion, and maybe just to indicate that one is serious about a suggestion. Masi, could you explain the reason for the bounty?

Comment: @Arjam: The reason is that I spend hours in SO-family per week. This means that I will spend many many hours in SO for the next 80 years. --- **I just want to improve the core system such that it is easy for us to use it.** --- Kip's answer is best what we can do without the team. However, I see that it would be much easier for us if the feature would be integrated to the main system. --- **I would like to know reasons why we could not integrate it to the main system.** --- **Is it a CPU problem or a bug in the design of comment system?** I would like to help if it is one of the previous ones.

Comment: @Masi - it certainly is something the team is capable of doing, there's no technical limitation.  Plus it would be all Javascript so there'd be no extra server load.  I think the only reason they would decline it is because they simply don't have the time to do it.

Comment: @Kip: You did it. It should not take much time to improve your script for the core system, when the development is done publicly.

Comment: @Masi yeah, but i'm much smarter than the team.  it would take them weeks.  (that's a joke).  seriously though, they could probably copy & paste the code from the javascript for the markdown editor, since it already has that functionality

Comment: @Masi: FYI code in my script has been updated. I fixed buggy detection of ctrl key, used much better built-in "ctrlKey" attribute of keypressed event object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit**: [this script now lives on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments).

Since this request is declined and Jeff is unlikely to be swayed by a bounty, I have written a GreaseMonkey script to add this functionality.  I've added Ctrl+B and Ctrl+I support.  I agree that it would be a good idea for this to be incorporated into the base code, but I guess it is not a high priority.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! --- My Firefox is getting heavy with Greasemonkey. I hope that we get a similar code to this to the core system.

Comment: Great catch! - I did not notice that when I read your code.

Comment: +1 when the person in charge won't do it, do it yourself.

Comment: Still not a high priority? Okay not high, but low priority? No? How about adding this one thing since many other features found their way in since 2009? Still no? Okay, is Jeff still around there to watch over what the good guys at SO are up to? ;P