# Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, waffles

Ever since we got the ability to format comments, I have abused it mercilessly. I put quick `code snippets` in there all of the time. And I find myself often highlighting a word or two and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, and then quickly mutter, "Ah, dammit," since it didn't do anything.

Can we please have formatting keyboard shortcuts on comments? I promise to make waffles.

**Update:** Kip made a timely edit of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5886) (didn't show up in my search, dammit) where this was declined, but there's a GreaseMonkey script. However, my waffle offer still stands.

Comment: What kind of waffles?

Comment: Homemade Belgian. With pure maple syrup. You can choose place of origin: Canadia, Vermont, or Upstate New York.

Comment: Random waffles, of course. :) (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: Eric, I've always wanted this!!!!

Comment: [Similar request over at TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4325/75272).

Answer (score 12):

I don't see anything wrong with this. If you are going to allow for the formatting, you might as well allow for the formatting shortcuts (if they are simple enough to implement).

I don't agree that the formatting is being abused or overused. I don't see how you can really have bold/italics/code get overused/abused unless the entire 600 character comment is made up of it.

Answer (score 11):

Especially the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> would be VERY useful. You know, not everyone has an USA Keyboard where the ` is conveniently placed! Many use a laptop without USA Keyboard and without a "true" numerical keypad, and so they have to fight to do Alt+Fn+M9O (096). I do think this is a **localization** problem (you program for your keyboard without thinking other persons could have different keyboards). It's like thinking everyone uses the `.` as a decimal separator.

Comment: At least do the code formatting: that is rarely abused... `except` when `there` is `a` `new` user `that doesn't `know` how to use the `site`. (But those users shouldn't *be* using the site in the first place) :D

Answer (score 6):

If this gets declined or you can't wait, you can use [this Greasemonkey script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments) to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcuts when editing comments.

Comment: I use it, however it does have some flaws in it: when you double click on a word to highlight it with a space after it, the script does this:  `*word_here *`. Also, I like that it adds `*|*` (`|` = cursor) on the post editor because I have a habit of [CTRL] + [B] → [LEFT ARROW] → *text here*, so that annoys me sometimes, although I'm getting used to it.

Answer (score 3):

German keyboards require an insane keystroke sequence to generate a tick character: <kbd>Shift-`, Space</kbd>. Yes, it is true: We need to press the <kbd>Space</kbd> key after having released the other two keys.

And adding code formatting to a comment requires doing that twice for every code snippet. I sometimes use the clipboard just for that one character.

Comment: For Italian keyboards, on Windows, it's Alt+96 (on Windows 10, there's also the Italian 142 keyboard which has AltGr+ù for it).

Comment: Being a user of a German keyboard, I'd say that this is overcomplicating the issue. Simply typing Shift+` and tapping the ` will produce two ` , now simply use an arrow to go back one, and start typing the code part, no need to go through the "space" thing

Answer (score 2):

Personally, since formatting was added to the comment feature, I think it's been overused in general. Once upon a time (pre-formatting), I thought it would be nice, maybe even helpful (eg, it might make comments easier to read).

I found the exact opposite once it was implemented and people were using it. I've used it a few times myself, but I'm worried that anything which makes it easier to do (keyboard shortcuts, a toolbar with buttons) might encourage others to use them even more.

Why am I down on comment formatting, when even I use it and I was once all in favor of it? Legibility. For some reason, once formatting enters the comment world, I find those comments harder to read onscreen. It might be their reduced font size, or there might be something more to it, but I really find the formatting distracting to the comment.

Of course, I expect very few (if any) in the community to agree with me on this one. :)

Comment: But *it* **makes** `comments` **PRETTY**!!! ...okay, I just really only use the `code` feature...

Comment: like everything else, it's ok when used sparingly, so I agree with your "let's not make it too easy to do this"

Comment: `Hi` @Jeff, it's been **10 years** now since [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756) _was_ asked. Can we have it _now_? `Please...` Just **BOLD**, _italic_ and `code`?