# Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K in comments conflicts with latest Firefox version

Tags: feature-request, comments, code-formatting, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Sadly the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> do not work in comments:

[Formatting Keyboard Shortcuts for Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments)

Typing <kbd>`</kbd> is [a pain on German keyboards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146006/169168).

But since the latest **Firefox** version 47.0.1 (or maybe earlier) Firefox opens a search page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>. Having used it so much  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> is saved in muscle memory and I forget and hit it in comments ... Boom! There goes my comment. When I navigate back the comment typed so far is gone.

This is killing me. Ideally, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> would work the same in comments and postings. But I would be happy to at least stop the hijacking. My search how to do it came up empty so far. Any good solutions?

Comment: Since Firefox single.digit Ctrl + K focuses on the search toolbar

Comment: @random: I remember solving a related problem (or this one?) some years ago, just not how any more. Maybe my solution was obsoleted by an update somehow making me think the problem is new. Either way, I would love any solution.

Comment: I can not confirm this problem. With 47.0.0 `Ctrl` + `K` changed the focus to the search box, but it did not open a search page (thus the comment was safe). After updating to 47.0.1 it did not even change focus - nothing happened pressing `Ctrl` + `K` (except any selection is cleared).

Comment: As a workaround for the keyboard problem, I have built the Ctrl + K functionality into [Edit Overflow](http://pmortensen.eu/) (currently Windows only) - it's then Ctrl + C, Alt + Tab, Ctrl + K, Alt + Tab, and Ctrl + V (it is faster than it looks). Originally, it was for when occasionally Ctrl + K did work in edit boxes.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but incidentally [Vimperator may block Ctrl + K](http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/vimperator/2008-May/001544.html)  (but it is a long time ago).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Your comment made me realize a workaround. Thanks a lot! I added an answer. If you want to add your own answer I would prefer and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

@Peter Mortensen's comment made me find a ***workaround*** for the immediate problem:

Firefox only jumps to a new *search page* when the *search box* next to the URL box has been removed from the menu (right click - Customize...) - which I did. (It's a useless waste of space, I search in the URL bar.)

After restoring the search box, Firefox instead moves the focus to the box and I am not hijacked any more. Seems like a Firefox bug.

(I would still love it if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> would work to format code / quotes in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't conflict since there is nothing to conflict with; the keyboard shortcuts for comments are unexistent and never were implemented.

Comment: Then let's call it a trap and not a conflict. The question remains the same.