# Ctrl+Q shortcut for adding quotes causes Firefox to quit

Tags: support, bug, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, editing-help

This is not a duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K in comments conflicts with latest Firefox version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281099/keyboard-shortcut-ctrlk-in-comments-conflicts-with-latest-firefox-version) because that only mentions comments, not posts.

While editing a long answer with a large block of text to quote, I held my mouse over the button for quoting, and noted that the shortcut to add quotes is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

The use of 'Q' makes sense, but it is also used to quit at least Firefox and Vivaldi.

Please note that this is not a question about adding comments and formatting of comments - this is in the main edit box, where questions are asked or answered.

Can this be changed in the website?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog I'm not sure this is the case - I use the ctrl+k option quite often without ill effects.

Comment: The question body mentions Ctrl+Q as well.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog But I'm not talking about in comments - I'm talking about the edit box for asking questions, or answering questions.

Comment: Ah, OK, I get it. Retracted my dupe vote.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog Thx.  I noted as AskUbuntu that it's not really a bug, but an annoyance

Comment: What OS are you on? I am on MacOS and I can't repro in Firefox. I'm guessing it's a problem in Windows or Linux.

Comment: @KodosJohnson because the shortcut for quitting is Cmd+Q on MacOS instead.

Comment: @KodosJohnson  This is Ubuntu 18.10 kernel 4.18.0-13, Firefox 64.0.1, Gnome 3.2(ish?)

Comment: I think this is only on Linux then, because on Windows the FF shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+Q

Comment: This is indeed Linux-specific.

Comment: @Marc.2377 I think it may be specific to Firefox on Linux

Comment: @CharlesGreen probably. I also use Chromium on Linux and it doesn't close when doing `Ctrl+Q`. And I hadn't noticed you also tested Vivaldi before.