# Make the "contact us" link go to a contact form, not a mailto: link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, contact

Instead of a `mailto:` link for the "Contact us" link at the bottom of every page, could you make it link to a contact form?

I use web-based e-mail, so I don't have a mail client set up on my machine.  So if I accidentally click on a `mailto:` link it ends up spending 30 seconds launching a copy of Outlook Express that I don't use that is not associated with any account anywhere.

This could also help you (the SO team) out.  You could give the users a "what are you writing about" listbox, with options like: positive feedback, found a bug, i have a suggestion, general question, etc.  Then the mail that you send to team@stackoveflow.com could be tagged as such (i.e. subject line "[positive feedback] this site is awesome!") to help you sort those e-mails better.  And if a user selects "I have a suggestion", you could display a "you could also try suggesting this on meta.stackoverflow.com" link.

---

**Edit**: Thinking about this more, the "contact us" and "feedback always welcome" links could be confusing to a new user.  They have very similar meanings but go to very different places.  Maybe both could go to a page that briefly describes what meta.stackoverflow.com is and what belongs there, *and* has a contact form.  And it can say "you can always e-mail us directly at team@stackoverflow.com" for those who prefer to contact you that way.  (Or maybe only the "contact us" link goes to the new page, and "feedback always welcome" is no longer a link?)

Comment: This sounds like just as much your problem as it is Dynamic Atwood Platoon's. `mailto:` links are commonplace, as are hooks that let you check web-based e-mail with any e-mail client.

Comment: ...as are sites that use contact forms instead of mailto links

Comment: Look, I'm trying to blame you here. Stop defending yourself. Please try to see it my way.

Comment: @Welbog: As a compromise, why don't you both admit that you're wrong and I'm right?

Comment: I refuse to admit anything!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm fine with this, so long as it has something like "or, you can always email us at team@stackoverflow.com" (with a mailto link) as well.  Don't force me to fill out a stupid form if I don't need to.

Comment: good point.  of course, you still have to kind of fill out a form in your e-mail client, all i'm suggesting is one extra list box, not a 5 minute survey.

Comment: And I agree with that.  But I hate sites that only have a contact us form.  I just want to make sure they still give out the email address.

Comment: I agree. There aren't many instances I can think of where I need a contact form to fill out if I am emailing them. I have often found those too restrictive because people tend to try and make you choose a subject type so they can forward it to the appropriate deleted/ignored folder.

Comment: Can't email get automatically deleted/ignored/laughed at/posted on facebook/ as the form post?

Comment: Sure, if he just wants to delete/ignore everything coming in. The idea of a form mail with subject options allows someone to ignore "bug" posts, because obviously the user is wrong and they are all by design.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just open up your web mail client and type in "team@stackoverflow.com" in the "TO" field?

Comment: Better yet, set up something in whatever handles protocols to open up your web-based e-mail software and fill in the `to` field for you whenever you click a `mailto:` link.

Comment: Because that is precious time that could be spent waiting for a contact form page to load.

Comment: opening a new browser window or configuring e-mail software is so much easier than entering text into a form field on the website you're already viewing

Comment: @Kip: Stop confusing a one-time effort with the longer-term effort associated with each e-mail you send.

Comment: maintaining e-mail client settings and browser e-mail settings on every machine i use is a one-time effort?  and entering text into a form field is a long term effort?  by that logic, why have "ask a question" go to a form when it could just be a link to mailto:questions@stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: Lots of machines, fair enough. But a contact form for every site you use is just as much overhead, since each site would have different fields with different names and different validations. That's what I meant by long-term effort. One single e-mail client has a smaller learning curve than a dozen contact forms.

Comment: @Welbog: where is the learning curve to entering text into a form?  you'd just need to enter a message, maybe a subject line, maybe select a general reason from a list box, and your optional e-mail address (required to get a response).  if anything is unintuitive or there are weird validations for a contact form, then the form is trying to do too much

Answer (score 1):

I don't like "contact forms". My email program actually has proper editing tools.

Have you tried Greasemonkey?

Comment: Drop that and try JQuery.

Comment: @Shog9 I've used it quite a bit (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15429/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12635/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/).  that doesn't change the fact that mailto: links are annoying for many users that don't know what greasemonkey is.

Comment: Well, that's my point - so are "contact forms". Your revised suggestion, where you advocate having *both* - that i could live with.