# Can you enable keyboard shortcuts Ctrl-K, Ctrl-B, Ctrl-I, Ctrl-L in comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible duplicates:**
>   [To have CTRL-B to make text bold in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5886/to-have-ctrl-b-to-make-text-bold-in-comments)
>   [Add keyboard shortcuts for Comments editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78007/add-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments-editing)

> **Update:** See this [GreaseMonkey script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments) that will enable these keyboard shortcuts in comments.

I often write little tokens or pieces of code in comments, and I never seem to remember the different syntax for links. Being able to use <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> would be a great asset here.

And while you're at it, you may want to enable <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> as well ;).

---

EDIT: apparently, this has been asked before many times and has been declined once already. If peer pressure and/or the community's wishes have value, I'd say leave this open and hope for a final **"yes of course, this has been asked repeatedly for almost 3 years, we'll implement this in the next release"**. (bolded with Ctrl-B ;).

PS: there used to be a "vote for feature" thingy. The sum of all the votes for this feature is way above hundred. Doesn't that count for something?

Comment: +1 Can I get some fries with that too? ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78007/add-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments-editing ... there's a duplicate chain you can traverse by following the links in the comments (most popular I could find; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75623/allowing-ctrlk-in-comments)

Comment: @Matt - the trail goes all the way back to ['09](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/formatting-keyboard-shortcuts-for-comments) :P

Comment: -1. Remember two patterns isn't big task and write it - isn't time consumption.

Comment: @LazyBadger: For me, it's not the problem of remembering the patterns, it's how tedious and fiddly the markup is to add; links in particular...

Comment: @Matt - you forgot to add "... for me". And you (I hope, I want to believe, I have a dream) may be *not a typical* representative of community here

Comment: What should Ctrl+K do? Comments don't support code blocks.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Ctrl-K also does inline code, aka simply adding backticks around the highlighted text.

Comment: Hope they get implemented. But frankly, I doubt I'll use them. I'm too `comfortable` [with](http://interhacker.wordpress.com/) **the** _markup_ by now.

Comment: At the very least, if not a full-out implementation in the SE core, having it available as a semi-official _plugin_ would be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Of 55 views, 17 upvotes, 1 downvote, if that counts for the masses, one could say that 30% cares enough to vote, of which ≈94% is in favor of this feature. That's a ***lot***, tx folks for the support!

Comment: [Problem solved](http://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments)

Comment: FYI- I've updated [my userscript on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/questions/2103/add-keyboard-shortcuts-to-comments) to now support `Ctrl+L` keyboard shortcut as well